# Determine if workdir has changes and index has staged changes (libgit2)

Tags: libgit2, git-stage

I've looked in `repository.h`, `index.h` and didn't found how to determine if workdir has any changes? And also, if index has any staged changes? I'm not interested in details, want just overall status.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git_diff_index_to_workdir` to check for changes in the workdir and `git_diff_tree_to_index` to get staged changes. The `git_status_*` functions do both together. If you only want a yes/no answer then pass a notify callback to cancel the diff after the first changed file is found.